# eBay API SOAP request works in SoapUI but not from shell

Tags: bash, soap, curl, soapui, ebay-api

The below works perfectly in SoapUI (that's where I constructed it), but when I copy the exact request and attempt to execute with cURL in the bash command line (cygwin actually), it says:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault>
   <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Client.NoSOAPAction</faultcode>
   <faultstring>no SOAPAction header!</faultstring>
   <detail/>
  </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
```

The command I'm using is:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "SOAPAction:" -d "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"><soapenv:Header><urn:RequesterCredentials><urn:eBayAuthToken>AgA***GO</urn:eBayAuthToken></urn:RequesterCredentials></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><urn:GetMyeBaySellingRequest><urn:Version>793</urn:Version><urn:ActiveList><urn:Include>1</urn:Include><urn:IncludeNotes>0</urn:IncludeNotes></urn:ActiveList><urn:OutputSelector>ActiveList.ItemArray.Item.ItemID</urn:OutputSelector><urn:DetailLevel>ReturnAll</urn:DetailLevel><urn:HideVariations>1</urn:HideVariations></urn:GetMyeBaySellingRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>" -X POST https://api.ebay.com/wsapi?callname=GetMyeBaySelling
```

I've used this exact syntax on other APIs with no issue, not sure what's different about eBay.

Comment: Fixed, as per user3090039's suggestion below to use SOAPAction:none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your wsdl. search for the operation which you are using to send this "GetMyeBaySellingRequest" request.
Copy the soap action from there and add in you command line

```
"SOAPAction: add soap action here from bindings or from soapui"
```

or in SOAP UI click on the operation and see at bottom left corner, you will see "operation properties". From there copy soap action value and put it in your command.

Comment: I tried that, all it says in the wsdl is <wsdl:operation name="GetMyeBaySelling">
<wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>. The wsdl is at http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/ebaysvc.wsdl. In SoapUI I don't see 'operation properties' but in 'raw' of the request it says SOAPAction: ""

Comment: ok, can u try to execute by removing -H SOAPAvtion from ur command.

Comment: try "SOAPAction:"" " or "SOAPAction: " provide space. I am little bit clueless here. In soap ui, at bottom left corner in request properties, if you select skip SOAP Action as true, you will get exact same error which you are getting here. Can you check for similar properties in curl also somewhere. I don't have any idea about that.

Comment: You are correct. I modified that command in SoapUI and I do get that same error. The question is how can I set it to 'false' directly in the command line. I feel like we're getting somewhere....

Comment: Have you tried double quotes, SOAPAction: "", Also try SOAPAction:none.

Comment: Awesome, SOAPAction:none did the trick! There was another error with quotes that showed up, but after correcting that, it worked perfectly!